# Insert Unicode Code into SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a dictionary table in sqlserver.

I have the unicode codes \u0C2D\u0C3E\u0C37 to insert. How to encode them when inserting into sqlserver  to show international character.

I am using NCHAR as the datatype for that particular column.

Thanks
K

Comment: Where are you doing the insert from? If it's via a data access library, most modern ones are Unicode aware.

Comment: \u0C2D\u0C3E\u0C37 isn't really unicode, its a proprietary string encoding of unicode characters. As per ChrisKelly, you will need to decode these characters (in SQL, or another language) and then you can insert them using the 'N' prefix e.g. INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (N'ΔЙק,๗あ叶葉말')

Comment: You mean first I need to decode the string \u0C2D\u0C3E\u0C37 and then insert?. I am using a sql script file to insert into the table.I have no idea how to decode those unicode codes..pls help.

Answer (score 5):

As nonnb commented, you can probably just use Unicode literal syntax in your INSERT statements. If for some reason you are unable to use the Unicode literal syntax and must encode a specific code point, use the NCHAR() function. The following example shows both:

```
-- create temp table for this example
create table #TestDictionary (
    [Key] nchar(10),
    Value nvarchar(100)
)

-- insert dictionary entries for the 3 specific code points mentioned

insert into #TestDictionary ([Key],Value)
values (nchar(0x0C2D), 'TELUGU LETTER BHA')

insert into #TestDictionary ([Key],Value)
values (nchar(0x0C3E), 'TELUGU VOWEL SIGN AA')

insert into #TestDictionary ([Key],Value)
values (nchar(0x0C37), 'TELUGU LETTER SSA')

-- If your keyboard allows you to type it into the script directly then it
-- is probably easiest to just use unicode literal syntax.
insert into #TestDictionary ([Key],Value)
values (N'క ', 'TELUGU LETTER KA')

-- Non-unicode string literals can also be inserted into NCHAR/NVARCHAR columns
insert into #TestDictionary ([Key],Value)
values ('A', 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A')


select *
from #TestDictionary
```

Reference and examples for NCHAR() can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182673.aspx

Comment: Chris,Thanks for the reply.  How to decode those unicode strings.

Comment: Chris, Thank you so much you made my day... appreciate your help. This is what I am exactly looking for.

Comment: How to create a word with multiple characters like this          insert into #TestDictionary ([Key],Value) values (nchar(0x0C350x0C460x0C280x0C15),'A Telugu Word'), I am getting an syntax error.

Comment: Chirs I got this working this way  insert into testtable values (nchar(0x0C35)+nchar(0x0C35)). Thanks